# ColdFusion EncodeForXML not working with UTF-8 characters

Tags: xml, utf-8, coldfusion

I am trying to create an XML file and I have a lot of special characters like ö, ä, etc. I am using `EncodeForXML` (previously used `XMLFormat`) but while on the browser it looks good, if I click view source and if I save the content as an XML file, those characters are converted to `&#xf6;`, `&#xe4;` etc

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
    <kunde>
    <kdnr>118133</kdnr>
    <fullname>Conny R&#xf6;nnb&#xe4;ck</fullname>
    <delname1>Conny R&#xf6;nnb&#xe4;ck</delname1>
    <delname2></delname2>
    <delstreet>L&#xf6;ftets gr&#xe4;nd 1</delstreet>
    <delcountry>SE</delcountry>
    <delzipcode>90363</delzipcode>
    <deltown>Ume&#xe5;</deltown>
    <phone></phone>
    <mobile></mobile>
</kunde>
```

Any ideas how to make the `EncodeForXML` function to display correct special characters?

Comment: Never mind. Switching to the "source" code view confirms it's the latter  https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2e1cf332-913b-4302-8524-326330eabdae/view-source

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to do with the XML? That's exactly what that function does. It encodes certain characters so they can be interpreted correctly by an XML parser.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="foo">
    <kunde>
        <kdnr>118133</kdnr>
        <fullname>Conny R&#xf6;nnb&#xe4;ck</fullname>
        <delname1>Conny R&#xf6;nnb&#xe4;ck</delname1>
        <delname2></delname2>
        <delstreet>L&#xf6;ftets gr&#xe4;nd 1</delstreet>
        <delcountry>SE</delcountry>
        <delzipcode>90363</delzipcode>
        <deltown>Ume&#xe5;</deltown>
        <phone></phone>
        <mobile></mobile>
    </kunde>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfdump var="#xmlParse(foo)#">
```

[image: xmlParse()]

**Update:** If you need to send the actual characters. then remove the `encodeForXML()` function and wrap each node's content with `[CDATA][1]`.

> The term CDATA, meaning character data, is used for distinct, but related, purposes in the markup languages SGML and XML. The term indicates that a certain portion of the document is general character data, rather than non-character data or character data with a more specific, limited structure.

```
<fullnane><![CDATA[#someQuery.fullname#]]></fullname>
```

Comment: I need to generate .XML file and save it on the server. An external app is getting the .XML and use it. They say they cannot use it in this format, it needs to show the special characters not encoded.

Comment: @AdrianCiocălău Updated for that use case.